# Search in label values in ASP.NET GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, datatable, label

I've got a GridView with several date columns.

In the database, the dates look like this:

```
180514
```

Using a function I'm converting the resulting labels into:

```
2018-05-14
```

I also have a textbox that allows the user to search the GridView and only keep those rows visible (using `DataTable.Select()`). The problem is that when a user enters `2018` it returns nothing because all dates are formatted with only the last two digits.

So, is it possible to do a `Select` on the labels themselves?

Comment: Why not do a search on the source data rather that the GridView contents? And storing dates as a string is always a bad idea.

Comment: @VDWWD I know it's bad but that's how my company does it...